# db_insert in Drupal 7 without field names

Tags: database

I have the following INSERT in a db_query, but feel like I should convert it to a db_insert, but can't figure out the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO {mytable} VALUES (23, 'foo', 'bar', 42)
```

This example is fairly short, but I do work with some legacy tables that have MANY fields.

```
$insert = db_insert('variables')->values(array(23, 'foo', 'bar', 42));
$insert->execute();
```

The above gives me "NoFieldsException: There are no fields available to insert with. in InsertQuery->preExecute()".

How can you perform an insert with db_insert without needing to specify each field name?
I can make it work in D7 with db_query([INSERT...]); but drupal_write_record does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this with `db_insert()`.  You could probably dig into the [`InsertQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/class/InsertQuery/7) class and get it done, but that's no different than what you're already doing IMO.

I have never seen `INSERT` without specifying column names, for good reason, although [apparently you can (mysql api)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html).  If you do this, it makes it more difficult for someone else to understand what you've done, and impossible to alter the table structure without causing headaches.

You can look at the way[`drupal_write_record()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) uses [`drupal_get_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7) to create the fields if you'd like to automate the process (although it would probably take just as long to write the `$fields` array one time).

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that was the case, and probably is much more time to get it to work.  INSERT without columns is standard SQL, but like you said if someone changes the table schema it would be a headache.  The table I am using is legacy and chiseled in stone at this point :)